# Cocos2d getChildByTag between multiple CCSpriteBatchNodes

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a game that requires multiple CCSpriteBatchNodes.

How do I communicate between the separate batch nodes using `getChildByTag` Whenever I used the `(GameCharacter *)[[self parent] getChildByTag: tagName]` I will only work for one class at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what I was doing wrong,it makes sense to me now. I will try to explain what I should have been doing.

I have about 7 batch nodes each with there own unique tag. If I want to check if an item from my "antBatchNode" comes into contact with an item from my "beeBatchNode" I would not do

(GameCharacter *)[[self parent] getChildByTag: tagName], because it will be pointing to the incorrect batch node.

I should have been doing it like this.
(GameCharacter *)[beeBatchNode getChildByTag: tagName].

When I was using [self parent] it was checking to see which batch node that class was added into. But because I have many separate batch nodes I need to be more specific with finding there location.

....If anyone can explain this better please do so. LOL. I just know when I did it this way it worked for me.